# Pros and Cons of using "as", "is", "DBNull", ToString() in C#

Tags: c#, .net, ado.net

When reading data from ExecuteReader. It returns me data in IDataReader. When I want to fill this data into my entities I will be assigning Non Nullable values in most of the cases to either Nullable types or Non Nullable types, e.g.:

```
int id;
string name;
int? age;
byte[] image;

example e = new example();
e.id = (int)dr["id"]; //unbox
e.name = dr["name"].ToString() //will result in empty string if dr["name"] is DBNull
e.name = dr["name"] is DBNull ? null : dr["name"].ToString();
e.age = dr["age"] as int?; // way 1
e.age = dr["age"] is DBNull ? null : (int?)dr["age"]; //way 2
e.image = dr["image"] as byte?;
```

**EDIT**

if `id` is primary key for the table and is NonNullable. But it is being used in another table where this key could be `NULL` then what should be the approach. Should that entity become NULL or exception should be thrown.

Comment: Just as aside... based on what I can see, that would be *perfect* for [dapper-dot-net](http://code.google.com/p/dapper-dot-net/); `Query<example>(sql, args)` would do all of that for you, optimized, cached, and without the risk of typos / lots of code.

Comment: @MarcGravell: Please add some more information to your comment, If I am not wrong this function would be mapping internally to an example entity inside DAL. If so, I am using the same practice and just to get the better approach, this is the simplest way in which I thought to present.

Comment: @vaibhav - life is too short to be manually mapping from DB to Entities nowadays.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the object reference is null, the is operator always returns false because there is no object available to check its type.

```
if (o is Employee) {
Employee e = (Employee) o;
// Use e within the ‘if’ statement.
}
```

The as operator works just like casting except the as operator will never throw an exception. Instead, if the object can’t be cast, the result is null.

```
Employee e = o as Employee;
if (e != null) {
// Use e within the ‘if’ statement.
}
```

Check more : [C# is and as operators](http://ekrishnakumar.wordpress.com/2006/07/08/c-is-and-as-operators/)

Comment: Second way is much more preferable, isn't it?

Comment: Here's [Jon Skeet's opinion](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7566212/when-should-you-use-the-as-keyword-in-c/7566229#7566229) (will find more)

Answer (score 1):

If you're sure in result type and it can't be null:

```
(int)dr["id"]
```

If result can be null and you know the type:

```
dr["age"] as int?;
dr["age"] as int? ?? -1; // default value
```

If result can't be null and you don't know the type:

```
Convert.ToInt32(dr["age"]);
```

If result can be null and you don't know the type:

```
object age = dr["age"]; // can be short, int, etc
!Convert.IsDBNull(age) ? Convert.ToInt32(age) : -1;
```

Answer (score 0):

My assignments would look as such:

```
e.id    = (int)dr["id"]; //unbox
e.name  = dr["name"]  as string; // String if string, null if DbNull
e.age   = dr["age"]   as int?;
e.image = dr["image"] as byte?;
```

The `as` operator works best for reference types (such as strings or nullables), because it will return null should the object I'm casting be something else, like a DbNull. This is exactly the same as doing the check manually, but more terse and easy to understand.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/209160/nullable-type-as-a-generic-parameter-possible) for some good examples of generic helper functions for your problem.

Answer (score 0):

In (comments) you asked for more info on my dapper comment; the point I was trying to make is that this is essentially a solved problem, and there are a range of tools to help here, from the complex and feature-rich ORMs (NHibernate, Entity Framework, LLBLGenPro), through middle-grounds (LINQ-to-SQL etc), through to stupidly simple (but very effective) micro-ORMs (dapper-dot-net, Peta.Poco, Simple.Data).

dapper-dot-net is the (freely available, OSS) micro-ORM that underpins stackoverflow/stackexchange. It is based on the ridiculously simple approach of mapping directly from returned column names to member names (fields or properties), such that the usage is simply:

```
var connection = ... // an open connection
int id = ...  // a record to fetch
var singleItem = connection.Query<example>(
    "select * from example where id = @id", new {id}).Single();
```

or

```
int customerId = ...
var orders = connection.Query<Order>(
    "select * from Orders where Status = 'Open' and CustomerId = @customerId",
    new {customerId}).ToList();
```

where `example` is the type in your code, with members `name`, `id`, etc. It takes care of all the heavy lifting:

- mapping inputs to parameters (see `@id` and `@customerId`, and how their values are provided)
- materializing returned records into objects in a very optimised way
- a few other tricks like horizontal multi-mapping, multi-grid mapping, automatic `IN` handling, etc

this means that *you don't have* to worry about details like `null`, `DBNull`, `Nullable<T>` etc, since dapper already handles all that for you, and is (thanks to some IL voodoo) just as fast at runtime as writing the materialization code yourself.