# Auto-dispose Threading.Timer

Tags: c#, timer, lambda, dispose

I want something very simple

```
// increment counter
Interlocked.Increment(ref _counter);

// automatically decrement counter after 1 sec
Timer timer = new Timer((o) => {
    Interlocked.Decrement(ref _counter);
    (o as Timer).Dispose();
}, timer, 1000, Timeout.Infinite);
```

this code, however, is not compile-able

> Use of unassigned local variable 'timer'

Any easy way to fix that? It must be `Threading.Timer`.

P.S.: I am not sure if I **must** call `Dispose`, it's obviously un-managed resource and it's `IDisposable`, still on [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.timer.aspx) they warn

> As long as you are using a Timer, you must keep a reference to it. As with any managed object, a Timer is subject to garbage collection when there are no references to it. The fact that a Timer is still active does not prevent it from being collected.

And I actually want it to be be collected (auto-disposed?). So, to dispose or to not dispose?

Comment: Do you really need a `Timer` from `System.Threading`. This could be done more easily with `System.Timers.Timer`. Also, I think it's clear for you why you get the error.

Comment: You can solve the *compile-time error* by separating the declaration and the assignment.

Comment: @MarcelN., yep. This is the catch.

Comment: @ByteBlast That will still pass `null` to state parameter

Comment: @ByteBlast, I tried and I failed, can you show how?

Comment: @ByteBlast: It will not work, it will still be null.

Comment: If it is not a periodic timer(period: Timeout.Infinite) then you don't need to dispose I guess. Not sure though. Will be back if I get more info.

Comment: Emphasis on *compile-time* error. One solution I found to solve this at *run-time* is to introduce a field and reference the field and not the state object.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's a pattern for that:

```
Timer timer = null;
timer = new Timer...
```

Now you can use `timer` in the lambda body. This is basically a way to make the compiler happy while doing the same thing.

Be sure to dispose of that timer. Timers *might* be backed up by an OS handle resource (the CLR implementation changed a few times I believe). A timer also contains a GC handle I believe. This is harmless not to dispose of *most of the time*. But who knows what rare resource exhaustion you can provoke with a high volume of undisposed timers.

Doing a little code review: If you expect a cast to always work, do not use `as` because `as` documents that failure is an expected case. Not: `(o as Timer)`. Instead: `((Timer)o)`.

Comment: God damn, it's like I'm a Java programmer.

Comment: @MarcelN. nobody wants to feel like that.

Comment: Take a look at the original comments. I suggested something similar but as others pointed out, a `NullReferenceException` will occur when you try to Dispose the timer :c Spot on otherwise.

Comment: @ByteBlast don't use the state parameter (because you're right with that - doesn't work). Use the captured variable `timer`.

Comment: @ByteBlast: usr means to use the timer variable directly in the lambda body, because it is accessible there. Not sure if you meant that.

Comment: Ah I see. I think I got confused because you still talk about the state object in your code review.

Comment: Thanks, it works now. *Tricking* compiler is the least thing I'd expect from `C#`. I also appreciate that code review part, reading [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7566212/1997232) reveals another my bad habit. You'd better include full example, with captured variable, I just got tricked until read comments =D

Comment: @Sinatr if you care to find out *why* we have to trick the compiler here post a new question. The rules make sense. This is one of the rare cases where they result in awkward code.

Comment: A slightly better way to do this is to use an array to encapsulate the timer inside an array. Reusing a local variable inside a closure can lead to side effects in some compiler versions. `Timer[] timers = new { null }; timers[0] = new Timer...`

Comment: @DmitryS. what side-effects are there? I'm not aware of that. Instead of an array I'd recommend `Box<T>`.

Comment: Here is an explanation: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5438307/detailed-explanation-of-variable-capture-in-closures . If you are using Resharper, it will show a warning.

Comment: @DmitryS. what's your point? Avoiding allocations? Your suggested workaround allocates as well and it does not even avoid the closure.

Answer (score 3):

Self disposing won't work if you don't keep a reference to it. You risk having it garbage collected, even if it's not periodical. So, it may be garbage collected before even it ticks the first time.

From the [System.Threading.Timer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.timer(v=vs.110).aspx) documentation:

> As long as you are using a Timer, you must keep a reference to it. As
>   with any managed object, a Timer is subject to garbage collection when
>   there are no references to it. The fact that a Timer is still active
>   does not prevent it from being collected.

On the other hand, it will be released via it's finalizer even if you don't dispose it (although not a good practice to rely on this). This can be seen in the Timer's source, [on ReferenceSource](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/threading/timer.cs).

Comment: I am not sure if that quote from the docs is accurate today. I believe a timer keeps a GC handle to itself to keep it alive. If @HansPassant is around he can surely comment because he knows timers well.

Comment: @usr: It does indeed keep a reference to itself, through an internal TimerQueue class which actually does the finalizing. Will look better into it and update (if Hans does not comment in the interim).

Answer (score 0):

If it's important that you dispose, you should try this:

```
class Foo {
  private Timer _timer;
  ...

  public void IncrementForASecond()
  {
    Interlocked.Increment(ref _counter);
    if(_timer != null)
      _timer.Dispose();
    _timer = new Timer((o) => {
    Interlocked.Decrement(ref _counter);
    }, null, 1000, Timeout.Infinite);
  }
```

This way, you are making sure that you always have a reference to the timer and that you are disposing of the previous timer before creating a new one.