# c# instantiate a List<T> using AS ... beginner question

Tags: c#, list, instantiation

I am in the early stages of learning c# and am currently "fixing" a project (as an exercise).

I've come across this code but I can't make sense of it.

`List<CartLine> cartList = Lines as List<CartLine>;`

Up to now my usage of Lists has been pretty standard

`List<T> newList = new List<T>`

And similar constructions.

I'm mostly hung up on where "new" keyword went and what "as" is really doing here. Is there another way of writing the above code that I may be more familiar with (to wrap my head around)?

FYI "CartLine" is a class:

```
    {
        public int OrderLineId { get; set; }
        public Product Product { get; set; }
        public int Quantity { get; set; }
    }
```

and Lines is linked by the IEnumerable

```
public IEnumerable<CartLine> Lines => GetCartLineList();
```

Sorry if this is a bit obvious for many of you. I read up on the MS Documentation of AS, but still a bit lost and i can't get great search results regarding its usage.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [When should you use the as keyword in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7566212/when-should-you-use-the-as-keyword-in-c-sharp)

Comment: Lines is declared as an IEnumerable of CartLine. This means it is a list of things that can be iterated, but it is not necessarily and instance of List<CartLine>. To use the instance as an actual List it needs to be cast. That is what the `as` is doing here. It is doing a safe cast to a List<CartLine> type to tell the code that it actually is a list. Whether or not this is a good idea in this case is not easy to determine from the code.

Comment: `as` tries to cast whatever it is handed to the given type. Lets say I have a class `Lion: Animal`. Now I can do `Animal myAnimal = new Lion();`. But now I can't use any specific `Lion` stuff on `myAnimal` so I could do `Lion myLion = myAnimal as Lion;`, and now I have the same object but I can use it as a `Lion`. Note here that it tries to cast. If the cast is not valid (because the object is not of that type) it'll return `null`.

Answer (score 1):

The `as` keyword is used to do a cast which is where you treat a variable of one type to act like a different type. From your source it seems the writer wanted to cast `IEnumerable` to `List` so they could use the properties of `List`. Following from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7617771/converting-from-ienumerable-to-list), `enumerable.ToList();` seems more appropriate than a cast.

```cs
using System.Linq; // At the top of the file

List<CartLine> cartList = Lines.ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

In C# 'as' is used to do a safe cast. If an object can't be casted to the desired type it returns null.

Linq `IEnumerable.ToList()` inserts all elements of an `Enumerable<T>` in a new `List<T>`. Only the List will be a new object, single elements will be the same.